# Dark theme for Mars 4.5 Mips?

Tags: themes, mips, mars-simulator

I am using [Mars MIPS Assembler and Runtime Simulator 4.5](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/)  for an assembly class and i find white background tiring when you stare at a screen for hours.

I want to change the editor's color to a darker tone (preferably the whole window) like **sublime text** or **eclipse's dark theme** .

There is no such option in settings so i tried to search the java code in the .jar to see if there is a resonable fix with no luck.

Is there actually a way to change the color , has anyone tried it?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it and ended up implementing a theme engine. Check it out: https://github.com/aeris170/MARS-Theme-Engine

Edit: I know link-only answers are frowned upon but answering this question without one is quite impossible given the complexity of MARS. It is impossible to include the essential parts of a possible solution since the said "essential parts" cannot possibly fit into a post like this one. The implementation I have has over 2k LOC. This doesn't necessarily mean there isn't a simpler solution, but given there are no other answers, it is the only solution we have. Therefore, please don't delete this answer, the link is not going anywhere, it will stay forever in my Github profile. By deleting this answer you would be wasting the productivity and time of many people who come across this "unanswered" question.